# HTML formatted text in demo for field html

Tags: html, odoo, qweb, odoo-13

in my model, I have a field

```
content = fields.Html("Content")
```

I will use this field to show on the website using

```
<p t-raw="page_data.content"/>
```

I want to set some demo data to my model and i want to set preformatted text like:

```
<record id="demo_text1" model="my_module_name.my_model_name">
    <field name="name">Name</field>
    <field name="title">Title</field>
    <field name="content">
        <b>some bold text</b><br/>
        <p>some ordinary text</p>
    </field>
</record>
```

In this part I have error, how can I use html tags in

```
<field name="content">here</field>
```

Comment: I think it should be `<field name='content'>here</field>` instead of `<field></content>`

Comment: add `widget=html` in field

Comment: Adam Strauss, sorry it's misprint. I mean </field>

Comment: Okay no problem just edit it for others and try `widget='html'` in html field in xml

Comment: widget='html' is for ir.ui.view, not working here

Comment: `<![CDATA[<span>-- <br/>
System</span>]]>` try like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `<![CDATA[]]>`:

```xml
<record id="demo_text1" model="my_module_name.my_model_name">
    <field name="name">Name</field>
    <field name="title">Title</field>
    <field name="content"><![CDATA[
        <b>some bold text</b><br/>
        <p>some ordinary text</p>
    ]]></field>
</record>
```

For further info look into [What does `<![CDATA[]]>` in XML mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean)